# After Clean Install of Ubuntu 22.04, Second Disk is Read Only

Tags: hard-drive, 22.04

My Computer has 3 disks, 2 SSDs (500 and 120), 1 HDD (1 TB). I performed a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop to 500 GB SSD. Before the install, both SSDs were clean (without any data) and HDD was full of my data.

Install went OK, everything is fine, except my 120 GB SSD drive is read only, I can not copy anything on it. I formatted it again using GParted but nothing is changed. Maybe I'm just missing something or there is another configuration problem.

Your help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use a command to chown it but probably easier to format it with Disks.

Comment: That's it, thank you very much. Actually I formatted it with Gparted but when I format it with Disks the problem is solved.
You may think of answering the question so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For normal usage prefer formatting with the included tool Disks instead of GParted.

Otherwise you can run `chown` for the mount point.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick and clear answer.